# Why are my tooltips in d3 not updating correctly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, stacked-chart

I'm using this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s79Zg/).  All of the tooltips are initially correct when I hover over the bars.  But when I click the weekview button to change the graph the tooltips don't get updated.

I believe the problem is in this section:

```
layer.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "layer");

layer.attr("fill", function (d, i) {
    return color(i);
    })
.append("svg:title")
.text(function(d){  
    return d[0].s;
});

layer.exit()
    .remove();
```

The append text is where I add the tooltips.  I thought the enter and exit would refresh the bars and therefore refresh the tooltips but it isn't doing it correctly.

How do I update the tooltips when my graph changes?

Comment: I'm not getting any tooltips at all in your jsfiddle.

Comment: I am getting tooltips in both Chrome and FF.

Comment: And I do see that after clicking the button `WeekView` the tooltips show wrong text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are appending a new `<title>` element every time the bars change.  The append should be done once on the enter selection and then simply update the value of the title in the update selection.

Here's a modified version of your code with some comments inline (I've removed the parts that aren't relevant to the tool tip):

```
layer.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "layer")
        .append("title");  // add new element under new layer

// add or update the value of the title element
layer.select("title").text(function(d) {  
    return d[0].s;
});
```

Comment: @Grammin Also try this. In the DOM inspector watch your SVG's title tags. And click `WeekView` repeatedly. You will see All redundent HTML tags getting appended. That is your bug, and this answer should fix it.